# Google Maps API v3: Change Map Type Event

Tags: html, css, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

Is there an event that gets fired when the map type is changed?

I have custom labels that need to change color based on the map type.  Is this possible?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try the maptypeid_changed event. You can then get the new map type using the getMapTypeId method of the map object.